# Modified classes are not picked by Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, classloader, spring-jdbc

I have modified few classes (like HiveConnection.class, HiveDatabaseMetaData.class, HiveResultSetMetaData.class, HiveStatement.class)  in **hive-jdbc-0.13.1-cdh5.3.3.jar**, and created a new jar which contains only modified classes and named it as **0_modified_hive_jdbc.jar**.

Those classes has some overriden methods which was throwing method not supported exception. Instead we created class in the same name, we logged message, and not throwing exception.

Placed **hive-jdbc-0.13.1-cdh5.3.3.jar** inside tomcat/lib (because org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver is referred as a driver name for a JNDI in server.xml)

I have placed all external jars like this,

```
/home/nages/external_jar/0_override/0_modified_hive_jdbc.jar
/home/nages/external_jar/hive/hive-jdbc-0.13.1-cdh5.3.3.jar
/home/nages/external_jar/others/commons-lang-2.5.jar
/home/nages/external_jar/others/spring-beans-2.5.3.jar
/home/nages/external_jar/others/spring-context-2.5.3.jar
/home/nages/external_jar/others/spring-core-2.5.3.jar
/home/nages/external_jar/others/spring-jdbc-2.5.3.jar
/home/nages/external_jar/others/spring-tx-2.5.3.jar
etc..
```

Referred these jars like this

**File** /home/nages/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/myapp.xml

```
<Context reloadable="true" path="/myapp">
<Loader className="org.apache.catalina.loader.VirtualWebappLoader" virtualClasspath="/home/nages/external_jar/0_overrider/*.jar;/home/nages/external_jar/hive/*.jar;/home/nages/external_jar/others/*.jar;/etc/hadoop/conf/;"/>
</Context>
```

Deployed my application (myapp.war) in tomcat.

find.jsp presented in myapp.war.

/home/nages/tomcat/webapps/myapp/find.jsp

Here is the piece of code presented in find.jsp

```
ClassLoader loader = clazz.getClassLoader();

if (loader == null){
        throw new Exception("Class Loader is null.");
}
String fileName = className.replace('.','/')+".class";
URL fileUrl = loader.getResource(fileName);
out.println("<b>Location : </b>" + fileUrl);
```

When I request for org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection in find.jsp, it returns,

**Location** : jar:file:/home/nages/external_jar/0_override/0_modified_hive_jdbc.jar!/org/apache/hive/jdbc/HiveConnection.class.

Inside war there is a java class, which has the following code

```
import     org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import     org.springframework.jdbc.support.rowset.SqlRowSet;

JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate(getDataSource("Hive"));        
SqlRowSet sqs = template.queryForRowSet(sqlQuery);
```

I am getting following exception

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Method not supported
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveResultSetMetaData.isSigned(HiveResultSetMetaData.java:141)
        at com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl.initMetaData(CachedRowSetImpl.java:726)
        at com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl.populate(CachedRowSetImpl.java:640)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlRowSetResultSetExtractor.createSqlRowSet(SqlRowSetResultSetExtractor.java:66)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlRowSetResultSetExtractor.extractData(SqlRowSetResultSetExtractor.java:49)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1QueryStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:447)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:395)
        ... 48 more
```

Question is why it is not picking org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveResultSetMetaData.class from overriden jar? find.jsp says the classloader picks this from overriden jar, whereas while executing query it picks from somewhere else.

Java : 1.7_45u
tomcat : 7.0.35

Comment: Might be Hive is using its own class loader to look only inside its own jar. Have you tried putting your overridden classes physically inside the hive jar, replacing the original ones?

Comment: That worked, but I don't want to do it that way.